# Need help applying substition/addition method to linear equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having a very difficult time solving these equations. For some odd reason I keep getting a graph answer. For example, when I try to solve $3x + 2y = 14$; it keeps telling me the answer is, $m=−32$, $b=7$ where $m$ is the slope and $b$ is the $y$-intercept. Which doesn't make sense to me since I have to apply the addition method which I did.

If anyone could help me figure out what I did wrong, so I could go from there, that would be great.

I need to **Apply Substitution Method For**:
$$x + 2y = 4$$
$$2x - y = – 7$$

And I also need to **Apply Addition (Elimination) Method For**:
$$3x + 2y = 14$$
$$5x – 2y = 18 $$

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "it" keeps telling you the answer.

Comment: The work I'm doing is giving me a plot answer, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You don't need a computer to solve this, these are very simple systems.  Solve the first equation for $x$, so that $x=4-2y$.  Then substitute that value for $x$ into the second equation $2(4-2y)-y=-7$.  Then solve that for $y$ and then substitute that value of $y$ into either equation to find $x$.

Comment: For the second system you add the two equations, thereby cancelling out the term with $y$ in it, you get $8x=32$.  That's easy then to solve for $x$, and you substitute back to get $y$.

Comment: Could you explain who(m)/what is giving a plot answer ? Whatever it is, I suspect you asked for in some manner. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot tell you what you did wrong, since you did not give us enough details. I can show you how to solve these systems of equations algebraically.

**Substitution Method:**

$$\begin{matrix}
 x+2y=4 & \quad &2x-y=-7 \\
 x=4-2y & \quad & \\
 & \quad & 2(4-2y)-y=-7 \\
 & \quad & 8-4y-y=-7 \\
 & \quad & 8-5y=-7 \\
 & \quad & -5y=-15\\
 & \quad & y=3\\
 x=4-2(3) & \quad & \\
 x=-2 & \quad & \\
\end{matrix}$$

**Addition (Elimination) Method:**

$$\begin{matrix}
 \text{Given (a):} & 3x+2y=14\\
 \text{Given (b):} & 5x-2y=18\\
 \text{Add (a) and (b):} & 8x=32\\
 \text{Solve:} & x=4\\
 \text{Multiply (a) by 5 getting (c):} & 15x+10y=70\\
 \text{Multiply (b) by -3 getting (d):} & -15x+6y=-54\\
 \text{Add (c) and (d):} & 16y=16\\
 \text{Solve:} & y=1
\end{matrix}$$

That last is actually easier to solve for $y$ using substitution after finding $x$, but I thought I would show you how to do the entire thing by elimination.